# Не могу избавиться от лишнего print

Tags: python, кортежи

**Задание:** Сформировать кортеж, содержащий нечетные натуральные числа в интервале [n; n^2] и вывести его на экран.
**Формат ввода:** Вводится натуральное число n.
**Формат вывода:** Вывести кортеж, содержащий нечетные натуральные числа в интервале [n; n^2]

```py
n = int(input())
    c = []
    q = []
    for i in range(n,(n**2)+1,2):
        if n%2 !=0:
            c.append(i)
            c = tuple(c)   
            print(c)

    if n%2 == 0:
        for i in range(n+1,(n**2)+1,2):
            q.append(i)
            q = tuple(q)
            print(q)
```

Comment: Сформировать кортеж, содержащий нечетные натуральные числа в интервале [ nn; n^2n 
2
  ] и вывести его на экран.

Формат ввода
Вводится натуральное число nn. 

Формат вывода
Вывести кортеж, содержащий нечетные натуральные числа в интервале  [ nn; n^2n 
2
  ]

Comment: `print(tuple(x for x in range(n, n*n+1) if x&1))`

Comment: переместите `c = tuple(c)` и `print(c)`, на тот-же уровень где стоит цикл `for`

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы создать кортедж с нужными числами можно прибегнуть к генераторам, больше известным как `генераторы списков`.

Генератор списков – это простой для чтения, компактный и элегантный способ создания списка из любого существующего итерируемого объекта. По сути, это более простой способ создания нового списка из значений уже имеющегося списка.

Общий используемый синтаксис генератора можно отобразить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример реализации в коде:

```
>>> [x**2 for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Обычно это одна строка кода, заключенная в квадратные скобки. Вы можете использовать генератор для фильтрации, форматирования, изменения или выполнения других небольших задач с существующими итерируемыми объектами, такими как строки, кортежи, множества, списки и т.д.

Решение:

```
n = int(input())
c = tuple(i for i in range(n,(n**2)+1,2))
q = tuple(i for i in range(n+1,(n**2)+1,2))

print(c)
print(q)
```

Причина почему мы тут используем ключевое слово `tuple` вместо `( )` чтобы `Python` не перепутал его с обычным выражением.

Что касается решения задачи:

```
n1= int(input())
q = [i for i in range(n1+1,(n1**2)+1)] # получаем все числа
o = tuple(i for i in q if i % 2 != 0)  # оставляем только нечетные
print(o)
```

можно так

```
n1= int(input())
o = tuple(i for i in range(n1+1,(n1**2)+1) if i % 2 != 0)
print(o)
```

Comment: здесь можно и без генератора обойтись: `tuple(range(n,(n**2)+1,2))` даст тот же результат

Comment: @SergFSM согласен, думаю вариант с генератором будет не лишним, тем более что я не нашел примера для tuple, а генератор полезен когда появятся дополнительные условия

Comment: @SergFSM на самом деле проверил Ваш вариант не сработало так как `n`нигде не объявлено, можете добавить в качестве полноценного ответа с полным кодом

Comment: странно, это и есть полный код: `tuple(range(n,(n**2)+1,2))` для `n=4` дает `(4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)`. Кажется понял - по условию надо вывести только нечетные. Тогда нужен генератор.

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно только один вывод при разных входных данных,ниже будет рабочий код, но я не могу убрать лишние скобки при выводе, а условие не срабатывает при правильных отступах(

Comment: #n = int(input())
#c = []
#q = []
#for i in range(n,(n**2)+1,2):
#    if n%2 !=0:
#        c.append(i)
#c = tuple(c)   
#print(c)
#
#if n%2 == 0:
#    for i in range(n+1,(n**2)+1,2):
#        q.append(i)
#q = tuple(q)
#print(q)
#

Comment: не совсем понял как у Вас получается рабочий код если метода append нет у tuple - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @Максим посмотрите в конец ответа я добавил решение, я использую 2 переменные чтобы было легче читать код, можно было в одну строку сделать

Answer (score 0):

для разнообразия добавлю еще вариант:

```
n = 4
odds = tuple(range(n|1,(n**2)+1,2))  # n|1 - округляет число вверх до нечетного

print(odds)  # (5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)
```